# OAuth2AuthenticationManager uses Principal but calls it's token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

```
if (authentication == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token (token not found)");
    }
    String token = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Should this be OAuth2AccessToken rather than the principal? [Principal is used for Token](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java#L82)

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected flow. Per the docs:

> Expects the incoming authentication request to have a principal value
>   that is an access token value (e.g. from an authorization header).